# What does the "segfault at X" kernel log message mean if X is very large?

Tags: kernel, memory, segmentation-fault, badram

I've got a device with bad RAM. Running memtest overnight shows all faulting addresses to be in the `0x7d0000000 - 0x7f0000000` range. I plan to replace the RAM, but until then, I've disabled a 2GB chunk around it with `memmap=`:

```
# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-25-generic root=UUID=5277c53f-b2cd-4301-8fdf-0b2119430870 ro memmap=2G$0x0000000790000000 quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

Those cmdline options do seem to be acknowledged by the kernel:

```
[    0.000000] user-defined physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009efff] usable
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x000000000009f000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000019e6a017] usable
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x0000000019e6a018-0x0000000019e7ae57] usable
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x0000000019e7ae58-0x000000002cb82fff] usable
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x000000002cb83000-0x000000002ed2ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x000000002ed30000-0x000000002edacfff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x000000002edad000-0x000000002f29bfff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x000000002f29c000-0x000000002fd0efff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x000000002fd0f000-0x000000002fd0ffff] usable
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x000000002fd10000-0x000000003cffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000efffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x00000000fe000000-0x00000000fe010fff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed03fff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x00000000ff000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000078fffffff] usable
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x0000000790000000-0x000000080fffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] user: [mem 0x0000000810000000-0x00000008beffffff] usable
```

However, I still get segfaults, ostensibly in the reserved address range:

```
Mar 09 20:47:40 srv0 kernel: udisksd[656]: segfault at 7fe974786218 ip 00007fe974786218 sp 00007ffcd10d1848 error 7 in libbd_swap.so.3.0.0[7fe974785000+2000] likely on CPU 7 (core 3, socket 0)
```

According to [this page](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/linux/KernelSegfaultMessageMeaning), I should interpret that as udiskd trying to write to the reserved address `0x7fe974786218` (error 7). At first glance, the `0x7f` address seems to match up with what memtest found to be bad RAM, but is off by orders of magnitude, since it points to a value of 140 TB.  My machine has 32 GB.

What, if not a memory address, does the `segfault at X` value represent?

Comment: Segfault errors can also be created by an errornous CPU. Check thermal state and power supply.

Comment: @paladin this is modern CPU with at least 8 cores, extensive supply voltage monitoring, dozens of voltage rails and internal error reporting facilities. Random memory address generation unit errors are *extremely* unlikely to happen like that. This isn't an intel 8080 motherboard from 1975…I think you might be confusing historically interesting problems with modern ones.

Comment: You would wonder what a bad power supply or some bad capacitors can do, or better, what they cannot do. There are also still production errors and every material is prone to errors. OP could also just operate the computer beyond its specification. Everything can fail and will so, it's just a matter of time.

Comment: Also I just read a technical article about a bug in modern Intel processors, which can lead to wrong calculations, caused by the internal automatic overclocking mechanism. So ya, stuff will break.

Comment: @paladin Please link to that article. You've done this before with electrical dangers, arguing with someone who studied electrical engineering on a level that really did not shine a great light on you: you greatly misinterpreted very sparse information on a different topic and then tried to grandstand to act as if you knew more than the rest of the present experts. I'm not playing this game. As far as I'm concerned, you're making this totally up, for – I don't know, internet clout? Yes, glitching is a thing, for example, but again, we're not talking an embedded board with singular supply rails

Comment: Sorry Marcus, in my opinion, it's you who has no idea. I also think you will not accept my opinion and I see no reason to continue this conversation. You might just have made different experiences than I've made. PS I'm not angry ;-)

Comment: Hey, how about simply linking to that article that backs your statements?

Comment: https://community.intel.com/t5/Processors/Blue-screen-only-when-Inter-Turbo-boost-is-enabled/m-p/1241085

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing address spaces here; this is *virtual memory* of the *process address space of the `udisks` process*. You reserved *physical address spaces*.

A segfault happens when a process tries to access a virtual memory address that is not mapped to any physical page, or that it's not allowed to access.

Physical and virtual addresses have nothing to do with each other, keeping a table to map virtual addresses to physical addresses is why your processor has a *memory management unit*. So the problem here is software accessing the wrong memory address – a bug.

Of course, that bug might not be a software bug, but caused by damaged RAM that you didn't reserve; nobody can know that! There's no guarantee that yesterday night's memtest still is relevant today, especially if there's problems on more than one physical address range. Honestly, what you're doing is quite hazardous – you know you have memory that might randomly corrupt data, you hope for the best that you caught all the offending memory and blocked it from usage. If the things you do with your computer *matter*, I wouldn't do that. Since you say you're planning to replace that memory, remove the whole RAM module *now*, and resume working if possible, or hurry getting replacement RAM.

Comment: Thanks! For the record, it's a development machine that's reimaged every few days so nothing stored on it matters much.

Comment: especially on a development machine, you want to know whether stuff fails because of software bugs; having sporadically wrong RAM in there feels like a bad idea!